# Difference between Moodle Web Service API and Moodle Web Service alone

Tags: web-services, api, moodle

I have read some statment in some articles about Moodle:

"The implemented functionality in terms of web services is less than half of the functionality offered by the web e-learning platforms. On the contrary, APIs offer a good set of functionality, but they are intended to be used by applications written in the same language, binding the external application with the platform programming language."

This statement implies that the Moodle web service is very limited compared to Moodle web service API. So, whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

A little clarification.

The **Moodle APIs** are interfaces that allow a programmer to directly interact with the Moodle instance, for example to get Moodle records in a plugin, or in a script. Moodle is in PHP, so you need to use those API with that language.

Among these APIs, there is the **Moodle web service API**. It's an API used to add a web service to a plugin of Moodle.

The **Moodle web services** are Moodle's **core** web services, that you get with a vanilla Moodle instance. To call them, you usually use a REST interface, xml-rpc or soap. So you are totally free to program in any language you want... (python, java, c# etc.)

It's true that nowadays the web services don't cover all the aspect of the LMS (for example, there isn't one for quizzes), so in case you need a web service, and it's lacking, you have to write one yourself. By using the... Moodle web service API. At this point you can call your new web service with REST, xml-rpc or soap, in any language you want.